# How to create usergroup with permission to delete customers in hybris through impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Need to create new usergroup with permission to delete customers in hybris through impex.

We need one usergroup which has the permission to delete customers

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

1. just login into the back office and create a new user group and give item access rights.
   Please follow this link:  [create usergroup](https://help.sap.com/viewer/c0234cf985ba4390b4eebe4a38a4457f/2105/en-US/8c282d8686691014b54f95ffbf322a6b.html)

2. Via Impex

```
INSERT_UPDATE UserGroup;UID[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=append]
;<<CUSTOM_USER_GROUP_NAME>>;cockpitgroup,employeegroup

$START_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;<<CUSTOM_USER_GROUP_NAME>>;cockpitgroup;;;;;;
;;;User;+;+;+;+;+;

$END_USERRIGHTS;;;;
```